# How to get position of click on UI element

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface

How can I get the point on the UI object a click or touch was made? From what I understand the normal way of Raycasting to see where a click lands can't be done with UI elements. And the OnClick event does not really provide any extra information.

Comment: `Raycasting to see where a click lands can't be done with UI elements` .. eh yes it can: [`GraphicRaycaster.Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.GraphicRaycaster.Raycast.html)

Comment: I also closed this one as a duplicate. If this is actually a different question feel free to explain why and we can re-open this one .. though this one was even more generic and unclear

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`IPointer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler.html) events.

```
using UnityEngine.EventSystem;

public class AScriptOnYourUIElement : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{
    //Detect if a click occurs - this is a callback, you do NOT have to call this
    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        Debug.Log(pointerEventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.worldPosition);
    }
}
```

There is quite a lot of other data the [`PointerEventData`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.PointerEventData.html) can give you, as well as other data that the [`RaycastResult`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.RaycastResult.html) offers.

If you do not want the `worldPosition` of the click, nor the `ScreenPosition`, you can convert these coordinates to the local `RectTransform` position of your object using [`RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle.html).

If you are using a `Canvas` in `Screen Space - Overlay`, you have to pass `null` as the argument for the `Camera` to the `RectTransformUtility`.

Another note to mention from the docs is

> When ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle is used from within an event
> handler that provides a PointerEventData object, the correct camera
> can be obtained by using PointerEventData.enterEventData (for hover
> functionality) or PointerEventData.pressEventCamera (for click
> functionality). This will automatically use the correct camera (or
> null) for the given event.

Let me know how this goes for you.